# Where does the minimal polynomial lie?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\theta = a + b \sqrt{D_1} + c \sqrt{D_2} + d \sqrt{D_1 D_2}$, where $a,b,c,d,D_1,D_2$ are integers. Is there any reason to believe the minimal polynomial for $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, without resorting to the notion of Galois conjugates and algebraically bashing out the particular polynomial? What about if we further assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_1},\sqrt{D_2})$ is biquadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta$ is an algebraic integer because it is a linear combination of the algebraic integers $1$, $\sqrt{D_1}$, $\sqrt{D_2}$, $\sqrt{D_1 D_2}$ with integer coefficients. Hence its minimal polynomial has integer coefficients.

Comment: It seems this answer is technically correct. I hadn't heard of algebraic integers before, and actually it seems like my question was really about why the algebraic integers are a ring, on one level. I'll accept it if you can give a brief argument or sketch of a proof as to why this is so.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for introducing me to this concept. Really cool.

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara, see http://modular.math.washington.edu/129/ant/html/node14.html for instance, especially Proposition 5.1.5.